# Reading the JSON data returned from ASMX

Tags: c#, jquery, json, asmx

I have written an ASMX service that looks like thus;

```
namespace AtomicService
{
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    [ScriptService]
    public class Validation : WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public string IsEmailValid(string email)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> response = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            response.Add("Response", AtomicCore.Validation.CheckEmail(email).ToString());
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using the Newtonsoft.Json library to provide the JsonConvert.SerializeObject functionality.  When call in Fiddler or accessed via my Jquery, I get this response:
[image: as seen in google chrome in this case]

The code for this alert is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://127.0.0.1/AtomicService/Validation.asmx/IsEmailValid",
                data: "{'email':'dooburt@gmail.com'}",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg["d"].length > 0) {
                        alert("fish");
                    }
                    alert("success: " + msg.d);
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert("error");
                }
            });
        });
```

And although I can *see* the data from the `msg.d`, I can't access it. I want to know what the `Response` is. How can I get at it?

I'm not entirely convinced my ASMX is returning the right type of JSON for this to all work.

Can anyone help? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your deserialized JSON object seems to have another JSON as one of its values. Try adding:

```
var data = $.parseJSON(msg.d);
alert(data.Response);
```

to your success callback to see if that's the case.

**UPDATE:** If that's the case then you have JSON-encoded your data twice – see [the answer by C. Ross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5248138/reading-the-json-data-returned-from-asmx#5248494) for a proper solution.

Comment: @C. Ross: You were faster with the solution to the problem than the original poster with the verifying if that double JSON encoding is indeed the problem here. I'll update my answer to reference yours.

Comment: This works perfectly rsp! Thanks very much.  I am curious as to C. Ross's answer however, but you have solved my original question. Many thanks :)

Answer (score 5):

@rsp's answer is technically correct, but the real problem is that you're doubly encoding your values in your asmx page.

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)] //This will cause the response to be in JSON
    public Dictionary<string, string> IsEmailValid(string email)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> response = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        response.Add("Response", AtomicCore.Validation.CheckEmail(email).ToString());
        return response; //Trust ASP.NET to do the formatting here
    }
```

Then you don't need to double decode in the JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks for the reply C. Ross.  I have done as you have suggested (required a `.ToString()` on `return response;`) but the response then is the object type as a string, not the object itself.  I had this with my previous version of the service and stumbled on a blog suggesting I serialize?

Comment: @dooburt [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791088/asp-net-scriptmethod-generating-empty-json) would indicate that it does do the serialization for you.  I wonder if it's a problem with Dictionary ...

Comment: @dooburt I think I figured it out.  Since your return type is string you have to convert to that.  Return the actual object type as my edit shows, then ASP.NET will format it to JSON for you.

Comment: thanks for coming back - hugely appreciated :) I'll try what you have suggested on the project I was working on and come back to update you. +1 just for coming back ;)

Comment: Thanks, this was driving me insane for the longest time! I suppose there's no need for JsonConvert.SerializeObject now. :)